# Rotation using keyboard -- glut / OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glut

I'm trying to make my object rotate depending on which axis is wanted (by pressing either x, y, z) and then starting/stopping the rotaion with the same key.  Here is my code:

```
#include <glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static GLfloat spin = 0.0;

void init(void){
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
}

void action(void)
{

}


void display(void)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glPushMatrix();


glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
glColor3f(1.00, 0.00, 0.00);
glVertex3f(0.00, 0.00, 0.00);
glVertex3f(0.00, 0.00, -1.00);
glVertex3f(0.50, 0.00, -1.00);
glVertex3f(0.75, 0.0, -0.75);
glVertex3f(0.25, 0.25, -1.0);
glVertex3f(0.50, 0.50, -0.50);

glColor3f(0.00, 1.00, 0.00);
glVertex3f(0.00, 0.00, 0.00);
glVertex3f(0.00, 0.00, 1.00);
glVertex3f(0.50, 0.00, 1.00);
glVertex3f(0.75, 0.0, 0.75);
glVertex3f(0.25, 0.25, 1.0);
glVertex3f(0.50, 0.50, 0.50);

glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
glutSwapBuffers();
glFlush();
}

//spin function
void spinDisplay(void){
spin = spin + 0.02;
if (spin > 360.0)
    spin = spin - 360.0;
glutPostRedisplay();
}


void reshape(int w, int h)
{
glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 15.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

}


//keyboard event handler
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
switch (key)
{
case 27: // Escape key
    exit(0);
    break;
case 'x':
    glRotatef(spin, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    break;
case 'y':
    glRotatef(spin, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    break;
case 'z':
    glRotatef(spin, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    break;
case 'r':
    glutIdleFunc(action);
    break;
}
glutPostRedisplay();
}


void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y){
switch (button){
case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
    if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
        glutIdleFunc(spinDisplay);
    break;
case GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON:
    if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
        glutIdleFunc(NULL);
    break;
default:
    break;
}
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
init();
glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutMouseFunc(mouse);
glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
glutIdleFunc(action);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

I have in the keyboard function each key that I want but I am wondering about glRotatef -- that is, whether it belongs there.  I created the function action that I intended on using to be called into the glutIdleFunc() but am unsure of how to incorporate the rotate into it.  Even if I can just get some clarification on how/why my keyboard call is incorrect would be great!

Comment: I would recommend looking at [this](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/animation/) and [this](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/keyboard/) tutorial. Actually, all tutorials on that page look pretty useful.

Comment: Or these tutorials: http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/

Answer (score 5):

## Keep the state

You want to have a current state of rotation written to some variable. So that when you want to draw your scene it will be known.

```
struct rot_state {
  bool rotating;    // animation/movement happening
  float x,y,z;      // current rotation values
  int current_axis; // 0 for x, 1 for y, 2 for z
}
```

The state keeps the current rotation and the program can work on that.

## Animation

`glutIdleFunc` does all the work in this example by incrementing (animating) proper axis `app_state.x += increment;`
Glut calls is every time when it has nothing to do and processes the loop. So it is used as a gate for the animation logic and then it forces a redraw on the frame.

*Although it could be done better I did not want to obscure the original code.*

## Display

When displaying the frame you can just use the infromation you already have and apply the rotations.

```
glRotatef(app_state.x, 1, 0, 0);
glRotatef(app_state.y, 0, 1, 0);
glRotatef(app_state.z, 0, 0, 1);
```

## Code

```
#include <glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct rot_state {
    bool rotating;    // animation/movement happening
    float x,y,z;      // current rotation values
    int current_axis; // 0 for x, 1 for y, 2 for z
} app_state;

void init(void){
    // Setting up initial app state
    app_state.rotating = false;
    app_state.x = app_state.y = app_state.z = 0.0f;
    app_state.current_axis = 0;

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
}

void action(void)
{
    // Animate the rotation
    float increment = 1.0f;
    switch (app_state.current_axis)
    {
    case 0:
        app_state.x += increment;
        break;
    case 1:
        app_state.y += increment;
        break;
    case 2:
        app_state.z += increment;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}


void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();

    // Apply the rotations
    glRotatef(app_state.x, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(app_state.y, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(app_state.z, 0, 0, 1);

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glColor3f(1.00, 0.00, 0.00);
    glVertex3f(0.00, 0.00, 0.00);
    glVertex3f(0.00, 0.00, -1.00);
    glVertex3f(0.50, 0.00, -1.00);
    glVertex3f(0.75, 0.0, -0.75);
    glVertex3f(0.25, 0.25, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.50, 0.50, -0.50);

    glColor3f(0.00, 1.00, 0.00);
    glVertex3f(0.00, 0.00, 0.00);
    glVertex3f(0.00, 0.00, 1.00);
    glVertex3f(0.50, 0.00, 1.00);
    glVertex3f(0.75, 0.0, 0.75);
    glVertex3f(0.25, 0.25, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.50, 0.50, 0.50);

    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 15.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

}

//keyboard event handler
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case 27: // Escape key
        exit(0);
        break;
    case 'x':
        app_state.current_axis = 0;
        break;
    case 'y':
        app_state.current_axis = 1;
        break;
    case 'z':
        app_state.current_axis = 2;
        break;
    case 'r':
        app_state.rotating ^= 1;
        glutIdleFunc(app_state.rotating ? action : NULL);
        break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
    init();
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutIdleFunc(action);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

This should get you started.

## Considerations

Keep in mind that this forces the rotations on particular axis that are local to the object. If you want to have more control on the rotation you would want to take a look at some quaternion -> matrix rotations. Theres an article on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) and plenty more on the internets.

Also the animation scheme is put into the idle function and you do not have a direct control on the speed of the animation. It is entirely dependent on the framerate of the application. There are also loads of great articles on how to implement main loops so that your logic/time can be handled precisely.

Comment: Great answer, hopefully this will not end up with your code just copy-pasted, there's a lot of useful info here.